# Why Doesn't The HTML 5 Geolocation API Support Promises?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title suggests I'm curious why the HTML 5 Geolocation only supports callbacks and not the more modern promise approach.

For instance, `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` requires a success and error callback in order to work.

Is it just a matter of time before it will be updated to support such a feature? If so, when?

Also, I'm assuming this isn't the only HTML 5 API that doesn't support promises. So, what is the reasoning for promise support on certain APIs and not others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Geolocation API is just older than Promises, that's it. You can easily wrap it to a promise: `const getCurrentPosition = (options) => new Promise((rs, rj) => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(rs, rj, options));` and then having: `getCurrentPosition().then(console.log)` (or use `await`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Geolocation API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation) was introduced around the time of Firefox 3.5 and IE 9.

Browser support for [Promises](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) arrived around Firefox 27 and isn't supported by IE at all.

In short: *Geolocation predates Promises*

(Speculation about a new Geolocation API that is based on promises would be just that: Speculation. Wrapping a callback API in a Promise is trivial though.)